# UIBackgroundModes with the location value,then app rejected

Tags: ios, background, core-location

My app includes the `UIBackgroundModes` key (with the location value) in its `Info.plist` file. The app was rejected by Apple.

**Apple's reason for rejection:**

*"We noticed your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist but does not include features that require persistent location. It would be appropriate to add features that require persistent use of real-time location updates while the app is in the background or remove the "location" setting from the UIBackgroundModes key. If your application does not require persistent, real-time location updates, we recommend using the significant-change location service or the region monitoring location service. "*

**Reason for using it:**

My app uses either significant-change location service or standard location service,because my app is available for both the iPhone and ipod touch. If significant-change location service is not available, app will use standard location service.

**Questions:**

- When app run on the background,that app whether need to add `UIBackgroundModes` key (with the location value) in the `info.plist` file or not?
- If not include,app can location successfully with standard location service? Thanks.

Comment: This gets asked all of the time. See all of the existing questions on this topic. Start with the ones listed under the "Related" section of your question. Several are an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

Yes user2082720, we have make sure that Why we are use location service in background mode.

please include the following battery use disclaimer in your Application Description:

"Continued use of GPS running in the background can dramatically decrease battery life."

Example:-
in case of location service background needed when we are using "geofencing" that time we have to use location service in background.

Answer (score 0):

did you need the location in background?
If you need the location only when app is in foreground then remove the UIBackgroundModes key from Info.plist because it will lead to drain the battery fast.

Comment: I need to location in background, but isn't persistent location in background. Then whether need to remove the UIBackgroundModes key in its Info.plist?